# Converted tflite model not working with tflite_runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, quantization

I have a simple pytorch model which I transformed into ONNX and eventually to tflite.
When I load the model and do inference with TF.lite, all goes well.
However when I try using tflite_runtime to load the model and do inference, I get the following error:

```
RunTimeError: external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/add.cc:385 Type INT64 is unsupported by op Add.Node number 70 (ADD) failed to invoke.
```

Here is the conversion code I'm currently using with TF2.6:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(path)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS]
converter.allow_custom_ops=True  # if omitted, conversion fails
tflite_rep = converter.convert()
open('exports/deep_snore.tflite', 'wb').write(tflite_rep)
```

I have checked many possible tf blogs but I can't figure out where the issue is.
The solution I can think of is to rewrite the model with TF, retrain it and transform it to tflite.

Comment: I would suggest to search for an GitHub issue mentioning similar errors.

Comment: I found the answer:
I was using the view() function in my CNN  model instead of torch.flatten. Once I did that change, it worked perfectly. I also changed my TF version from 2.6 to 2.2